# bash /usr/bin/ng: No such file or directory in Angular

Tags: angular

When I run my Angular project by `ng serve`, it gives this error:

> bash: /usr/bin/ng: No such file or directory

I have run `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: To use this command, you must run your command line utility as root / as administrator. Which system are you using ? MacOS ? Linux ?  Windows ?

Comment: (I am talking about the `npm install -g`)

Comment: I am using Linux 16.04.

Comment: did you install angular-cli as root ? (or using `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`)

Answer (score 29):

I faced the same problem and here is what worked for me.

1) Find the .bashrc file by running -

```
ls -la ~/ | more
```

2) Open in editor, in my case emacs -

```
emacs ~/.bashrc
```

3) Add an alias at the end of the file pointing to the right path of your ng directory & save the file. e.g. -

```
alias ng="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
```

4) Either restart the terminal or refresh it using -

```
sudo source ~/.bashrc
```

5) Now test by running `ng -v`

Comment: In my case, ng file was named ng.js and I had to use
alias ng="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js"

Answer (score 17):

**Step 1** -
first of all run the below command and check wheather the **error** resolved if not then follow (**STEP 2**) .

1:- alias ng="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"

**Step 2** -
Just remove and install @angular/cli.

2:- sudo npm remove -g @angular/cli

3:- sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

It resolves the issue.

**If you are facing same issue again refer the url.**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47894921/11983640

Comment: does it have to be installed as root?

Comment: Step 1 worked!! But can you please elaborate what is it doing?

Comment: The correct path which worked with me is:
alias ng="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js"

Answer (score 9):

Use this command ,I resolved my issue after angular cli installed

> alias ng="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"

Answer (score 6):

Run this in root
$ sudo su

# sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: Best working solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you had run `npm install -g @angular/cli` with root.
Try to remove angular-cli and then reinstall with sudo

```
sudo npm remove -g @angular/cli
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 5):

I reinstalled angular and then restarted the terminal. It worked fine

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue when `@agnular/cli` is intended to be installed on CI.

I resolved this by simply creating an empty folder just before you're about to execute any of ng-related commands

```sh
$ mkdir node_modules
$ ng --version
```

Answer (score 1):

It should give this alias,
alias ng="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js"

then use
sudo npm remove -g @angular/cli
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to use command like this:

```
alias ng="/Users/{user_name}/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
```

before this command i made:

```
npm cache clean, uninstall -g angular-cli, npm install -g angular-cli
```

Terminal output had error like this:

EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng' -> '/Users/{user_name}/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin/ng'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/{user_name}/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.1/bin/ng

It helps me to prepare new alias path and it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried all above solutions nothing worked for me then following worked for me

```
node --version
v6.17.1
```

it was very old version thus I planed to upgrade it, currently i am on centos7

```
sudo -i
sudo curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x  | bash -
```

As I was already having node and npm installed i need to uninstall it first

```
sudo yum remove -y nodejs npm
sudo yum install -y nodejs  # to install Node.js 16.x and npm
```

Then Finally

```
[root@e56d240b471c ~]# node --version
v16.5.0
[root@e56d240b471c ~]# npm --version
7.19.1
[root@e56d240b471c ~]# ng v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 12.1.3
Node: 16.5.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 7.19.1
OS: linux x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1201.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         12.1.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   12.1.3 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          12.1.3 (cli-only)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the message that my request was deprecated. I removed this file: /usr/local/bin/ng and ran: sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix it is to create the symlink manually:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng /usr/bin/ng
```

Note that when you install any package using `npm` it prints the symlinks that were just created (example for installing yarn):

```
sudo npm install -g yarn

> yarn@1.22.11 preinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/yarn
> :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)

/usr/bin/yarn -> /usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
/usr/bin/yarnpkg -> /usr/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
+ yarn@1.22.11
added 1 package in 1.274s
```

In your case symlink (`/usr/bin/ng`) does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and here is what worked for me.

1. Find the .bashrc file by running `ls -la ~/ | more`
2. Open in editor, in my case emacs `emacs ~/.bashrc`
3. Add an alias at the end of the file like this pointing to the right path of your `ng` directory `alias ng="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"`
   4.save the file and install it by running  `sudo source ~/.bashrc`

Now test by running `ng -v`

Comment: This answer is directly copied from the existing answer below. Please use edit option if you want to suggest formatting and do not copy an existing answer and post as your own. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The error message **"bash: /usr/bin/ng: No such file or directory"** indicates that the system is unable to locate the ng (Angular CLI) executable file in the specified location (/usr/bin/ng).

**This issue may occur if:**

- Angular CLI is not installed.
- The PATH environment variable is not set correctly.

**To resolve the issue:**

1. Check if **Angular CLI** is installed by running ng version in the terminal.
2. If not installed, install Angular CLI globally using the command **npm install -g @angular/cli.**
3. Verify that the PATH environment variable is set correctly by running echo $PATH. The /usr/bin directory should be included in the list of directories.

If the issue persists, try re-installing Angular CLI and restarting your terminal or system.