# Angular stopped working

Tags: linux, angular, angular-cli

Last night out of the blue my ng serve command started giving this error

```
bash: /usr/bin/ng: No such file or directory
```

I've since then done some fiddling and I have gotten the following
if I uninstalled and use

```
sudo npm install -g angular-cli
```

I get the error

```
ng command not found
```

if I uninstalled and use

```
 sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Edit: Everything appears fine after the above line but when I run `ng serve` I get the error below (sorry forgot to add this part)

I get

```
The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
    at Object.CompilerCliIsSupported (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngtools_api.js:25:15)
    at new AotPlugin (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:28:23)
    at _createAotPlugin (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:92:16)
    at Object.getNonAotConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:100:19)
    at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js:41:37)
    at Class.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:71:98)
    at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:123:26)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I tried following the instruction in the only answer to this question ([bash /usr/bin/ng: No such file or directory in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870247/bash-usr-bin-ng-no-such-file-or-directory-in-angular)) but was unsuccessful.

Edit:  `ng -v` gives

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 8.2.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Update:  I if I create a new angular project or unzip one sent to me from another computer ng serve works.  The only explanation I can think if is that somehow the paths got messed up.

Answer (score 0):

With the command

```
sudo npm install -g angular-cli
```

you installed version 1.0 of the `azure cli` globally. You should have removed it with

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

I also would delete the `node_modules` folder of your project and run an `npm install` for a fresh install.

If that is not working I would try to reinstall the latest `azure cli`.

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
sudo npm cache verify
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```