# Getting error on angular version command

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I execute `ng -v` it shows:

> bash: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng: No such file or
>   directory.

I tried doing the solution in [bash /usr/bin/ng: No such file or directory in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870247/bash-usr-bin-ng-no-such-file-or-directory-in-angular) but could not find node_modules folder in `/usr/local/lib` folder. Even after running `sudo npm install @angular/cli@6.2.0-beta.1`, I get the same error.

Any help please

Comment: run the following command `sudo npm i -g @angular/cli@6.2.0-beta.1`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the package globally

```
sudo npm i -g @angular/cli@6.2.0-beta.1
```

Comment: When i run this command , it says "npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/{MYNAME}/package.json'". This error is caused i think because we are using 'run' in command

Comment: `run` is used to run scripts from `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

I've been experienced the exact same error previously. In my case, it was caused by running this command in the wrong place that has unnecessary `package.json` and `package-lock.json` in an outdated format.

Please double check if you are executing `ng -v` in the correct path, and both `package.json` and `package-lock.json` are updated in the correct states.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it. Just for info if any one is willing to know

```
1) npm uninstall -g angular-cli
2) npm cache clean --force
3) sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@6.2.0-beta.1
4) added line 'alias ng="/home/XXXXXX/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"' in ~/.bashrc
```

Created a new terminal and checked ng -v and it worked.

I want to create a pwa app so i hope cli 6.2 should work fine