# Angular ng no such file or directory

Tags: angular

i'm trying to serve an angular app in a server, the thing is, the command ng serve throws the "No such file or directory" but the ng is there, see image below .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'cd' back to the level of the package.json file and have angular Cli installed globally.

Comment: the server does not have internet connection, and the cli was installed globally in the local environment

Comment: Check this tread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870247/bash-usr-bin-ng-no-such-file-or-directory-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute it like this:

```
/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

Since you didn't installed it globally it is only available in this project environment.

Comment: Not found again